# NullPointer when using Scanner to read large file as resource from packaged jar

Tags: java, jar

I'm on Mac OSX 10.12.6

This program listens for Tcp requests on the network, reads an XML request and responds with XML.

When I run this program via the command line:

> java -classpath target/classes/ com.mycompany.ocip.server.OCIServer

It runs fine and responds to all XML requests.

However, when I run it as a jar file:

> java -jar target/ocip-server-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I get an exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: source
>       at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
>       at java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:578)
>       at com.mycompany.ocip.server.OCIProtocol.readFile(OCIProtocol.java:56)
>       at com.mycompany.ocip.server.OCIProtocol.processInput(OCIProtocol.java:31)
>       at com.mycompany.ocip.server.OCIServer.main(OCIServer.java:85)

When a large response needs to be sent.

The line the exception pertains to is in the code that reads the XML file to be sent in response: (from OCIProtocol.java, in case that's relevant)

```
public String readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8"); // <-- exception
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
    String text = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
    scanner.close();
    return text;
}
```

The strange thing is this exception:

1. only happens when running as a jar file
2. only happens when reading a 'large' xml file from the classpath, e.g. 25MB (several smaller files succeed)

I've tried it dozens of times.

The exception doesn't occur when running the program with the classpath set to the target//classes folder

What could cause this behaviour?

EDIT:
As requested: tar output:
Please note that all other XML files get send by the server without issue, except `examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse-Client1.xml`, (maybe relevant: this file is 25MB wheras the others are smaller files)

```
user$ tar -tf target/ocip-server-jar-with-dependencies.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/mycompany/
com/mycompany/ocip/
com/mycompany/ocip/server/
examples/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/bw-ocip-server/
META-INF/maven/bw-ocip-server/bw-ocip-server/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany/
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany/bw-ocip-server/
com/mycompany/ocip/server/OCIProtocol.class
com/mycompany/ocip/server/OCIServer.class
examples/AuthenticationResponse.xml
examples/GroupDnGetActivationListResponse.xml
examples/LoginResponse.xml
examples/LogoutResponse.xml
examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaAssignListRequest.xml
examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaAssignListResponse.xml
examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetAssignedListRequest.xml
examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetAssignedListResponse.xml
examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringProfileGetResponse-NoSMP.xml
examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringProfileGetResponse.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse-Client1.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse-NoSP.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse2.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse3.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse4.xml
examples/ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListResponse5.xml
examples/ServiceProviderGetListResponse.xml
examples/SystemCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetListRequest.xml    
examples/SystemCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetListResponse.xml
examples/UserGetListInGroupResponse.xml
META-INF/maven/bw-ocip-server/bw-ocip-server/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/bw-ocip-server/bw-ocip-server/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany/bw-ocip-server/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/com.mycompany/bw-ocip-server/pom.xml
```

The call to readFile is as follows:

```
public String processInput(String theInput) throws IOException {

   String theOutput = "";

  if (theInput.contains("LoginRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/LoginResponse.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("LogoutRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/LogoutResponse.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryList")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/ServiceProviderDNGetSummaryListResponse-Client1.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("UserGetListInGroupRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/UserGetListInGroupResponse.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringProfileGetRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringProfileGetResponse.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaAssignListRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaAssignListResponse.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetAssignedListRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/ServiceProviderCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetAssignedListResponse.xml");
  } else if (theInput.contains("SystemCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetListRequest")) {
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/SystemCommunicationBarringCriteriaGetListResponse.xml");
  } else
    theOutput = this.readFile("/examples/AuthenticationResponse.xml");

   return theOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have finally provided sufficient detail, the problem here is that resources in JAR files are case-sensitive while the file system evidently is not.

> the file is present in the jar file, and is named exactly as it is on the filesystem

No it isn't. You have a case difference (`DN/Dn`) between your resource string name and your filename.

Comment: As stated in the question (from the beginning), I am using Mac OSX (10.12.6)